# Как сделать случайную выборку MySQL чтоб не грузить сервер?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Встала задача - сделать случайную выборку 10 строк из таблицы. В таблице пока мало записей, но вскоре она разрастётся до десятков тысяч. Дело осложняется тем, что есть дополнительное условие выборки, а также в id могут встречаться дыры. По сути сам запрос прост:

```
SELECT id, title, desc FROM my_table WHERE group_id=25 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

Но в таком виде он в будущем, наверно, станет сильно грузить сайт...
Вопрос: посоветуйте, как лучше оптимизировать всё это дело?

Можно как с помощью sql, так и на php.
Заранее дико благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53089/discussion-on-question-by-------m).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно вот так:

```
SELECT id, title, desc
  FROM my_table AS r1 JOIN
       (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                     (SELECT MAX(id)
                        FROM my_table)) AS id)
        AS r2
 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id AND group_id=25
 ORDER BY r1.id ASC
 LIMIT 10
```

В моем случая в таблице с 8 миллионами записей отрабатывает за 202ms, когда с `ORDER BY RAND()` за 15s

> Оригинальный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast/4329447#4329447) от [@Riedsio](http://nhttps://stackoverflow.com/users/502502/riedsio)

Comment: Ок, я попробую так, спасибо. О впечатлениях отпишусь.

Comment: Это решение **очень** плохо применимо из-за `group_id`.

Comment: @vp_arth в плане? Если использовать индекс для поля `group_id` то не вижу проблем. Возможно я не прав

Comment: Это решение тем лучше, чем более диапазон id похож на `range(1..max(id))` как вы думаете, на что похож диапазон id двадцать пятой группы?

Comment: @vp_arth да, я понял о чем вы, и я понял проблему